# How do I unit test the properties of a variable declared in a method under test

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, nunit, moq

I have a service layer method that recieves an object(Dto) as a parameter.

Within that method I new up a business object and i pass the values of the properties of the Dto to the properties of the business object. I then pass the business object as a parameter to a repository method call.

How will my unit test ensure that the business object declared in the service method under test receives the right value into its properties?

Comment: I maybe wrong or correct my understandinbg,I thought unit testing covers testing as much as possible everything that happens with in the service method under test. The business object is declared within the method. I want to ensure that the property values of the buiness object are the same value as the properties in the Dto passed in as a parameter to the service method under test.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question rather than clarify it in a comment.

Comment: @Tunji : see my updated answer with a detailed example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock the repository (I hope that you can inject it into the service layer) and check whether the business object passed into the repository has the expected property values.

**EDIT: An example**

---

**Infrastructure:**

```
public interface IRepository
{
   void Add(BusinessObject item);
}

public sealed class ServiceLayerContext
{
   private readonly IRepository repository;

   public ServiceLayerContext(IRepository repository)
   {
       this.repository = repository;
   }

   public void ProcessDto(IDtoObject dto)
   {
       var businessObject = this.CreateBusinessObject(dto);
       this.repository.Add(businessObject);
   }

   private BusinessObject CreateBusinessObject(IDtoObject dto)
   {
   }
}
```

**Test pseudocode (because RhinoMockі not the Moq):**

```
   [Test]
   public void ShouldCreateBusinessOBjectWithPropertiesInitializedByDtoValues()
   {
      // ARRANGE
      // - create mock of the IRepository
      // - create dto
      // - setup expectations for the IRepository.Add() method
      //   to check whether all property values are the same like in dto   
      var repositoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository>();
      var dto = new Dto() { ... };
      BusinessObject actualBusinessObject = null;
      repositoryMock.Expect(x => x.Add(null)).IgnoreArguments().WhenCalled(
        (mi) => 
        {
            actualBusinessObject = mi[0] as BusinessObject;            
        }).Repeat().Any();

      // ACT
      // - create service layer, pass in repository mock
      // - execute svc.ProcessDto(dto)     
      var serviceLayerContext = new ServiceLayerContext(repositoryMock);
      serviceLayerContext.ProcessDto(dto);

      // ASSERT
      // - check whether expectations are passed
      Assert.IsNotNull(actualBusinessObject);
      Assert.AreEqual(dto.Id, actualBusinessObject.Id);
      ...
   }
```

Comment: I can definately inject the repository, its loosely coupled. I'll try and test for the expectations

Comment: Thank you sll, makes a lot of sense. I'll refactor my code by creating a private sub routine that will have the sole responsibility of creating my business object and passing dto values the business object values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help.
The sample code below uses moq and its written in vb.net for other vb.net programmers that might of had similar challenges.

**Concrete Class**

```
Public Class UserService
Implements IUserService

Private ReadOnly userRepository As IUserRepository

Public Sub New( _
   ByVal userRepository As IUserRepository)

    Me.userRepository = userRepository

End Sub

Public Sub Edit(userDto As Dtos.UserDto) Implements Core.Interfaces.Services.IUserService.Edit

    Try
        ValidateUserProperties(userDto)

        Dim user = CreateUserObject(userDto)

        userRepository.Edit(user)


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Sub

Private Function CreateUserObject(userDto As Dtos.UserDto) As User Implements  Core.Interfaces.Services.IUserService.CreateUserObject
    Dim user = New User With {.Id = userDto.Id, _
              .UserName = userDto.UserName, _
              .UserPassword = userDto.UserPassword, _
              .Profile = New Profile With {.Id = userDto.ProfileId}}
    Return user
End Function
Sub ValidateUserProperties(userDto As Dtos.UserDto)



End Sub
```

**Test Class**

```
<TestFixture()>
Public Class UserServiceTest

Private userRepository As Mock(Of IUserRepository)
Public serviceUnderTest As IUserService

<SetUp()>
Public Sub SetUp()

    userRepository = New Mock(Of IUserRepository)(MockBehavior.Strict)

    serviceUnderTest = New UserService(userRepository.Object)


End Sub

<Test()>
Public Sub Test_Edit()
    'Arrange
    Dim userDto As New UserDto With {.UserName = "gbrown", .UserPassword = "power", .Id = 98, .ProfileId = 1}

    Dim userObject As User = Nothing

    userRepository.Setup(Sub(x) x.Edit(It.IsAny(Of User))) _
    .Callback(Of User)(Sub(m) userObject = m)

    'Act

    serviceUnderTest.Edit(userDto)


    'Assert

    userRepository.Verify(Sub(x) x.Edit(It.IsAny(Of User)), Times.AtLeastOnce())

    Assert.NotNull(userObject)
    Assert.AreEqual(userDto.Id, userObject.Id)
    Assert.AreEqual(userDto.ProfileId, userObject.Profile.Id)
    Assert.AreEqual(userDto.UserName, userObject.UserName)
    Assert.AreEqual(userDto.UserPassword, userObject.UserPassword)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So this helped ypu? In this case you can accept an answer to indicate that